# AWS Lambda Function - Kinesis Data Stream Processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

Iam writing a AWS Lambda function to consume from a Kinesis data stream and write to a DynamoDB file after some processing. The sample stream is as below:

```
{'DateTime': Timestamp('2021-04-29 10:30:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'), 'ticker': 'MSFT', 'Open': 250.9600067138672, 'Close': 249.1999969482422 }
{'DateTime': Timestamp('2021-04-29 11:30:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'), 'ticker': 'MSFT', 'Open': 249.2100067138672, 'Close': 250.0399932861328}
```

My Lambda function code is as below:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dynamodb_res = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')

    eventText =json.dumps(event)
    dict1 = json.loads(eventText)
    pprint(dict1, sort_dicts=False)
    table = dynamodb_res.Table('Table1')
    for i in dict1:
      response = table.put_item(Item=i)
```

I keep getting the below error. Any idea on how to rectify this..

```
[ERROR] ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Item, value: Records, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a look at the `event` object your lambda receives. It is already `dict`, so there 2 operations make no practical sense:

   ```
   eventText =json.dumps(event)
   dict1 = json.loads(eventText)
   ```
2. `for i in dict1` doesn't do what you expect it to do. In Python, when you iterate through `dict`, each next iteration will return next key, which is `str` in this case:

   ```
   test = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
   for key in test:
       print(f"Current key: {key}, corresponding value: {test[key]}")
   >> Current key: a, corresponding value: 1
   >> Current key: b, corresponding value: 2
   ```

   So what you probably intended to do is:

   ```
   for i in event["Records"]:
       response = table.put_item(Item=i)
   ```

Comment: How do i access each row of this list of dictionaries..

Comment: `for i in event["Records"]` - that's what goes through list of dicts and returns then one by one.